# How to make transactions on multiple data tables in Firebase?

Tags: swift, firebase, transactions, firebase-realtime-database

I've an application, which uses Firebase. I have a new post adding. And when I make it, I do a number of operations in database, like:

1. Add new post info to Posts node
2. Add Id of the new post to Users node
3. Upload media to storage
4. etc.

So, for example, user can close application on step 2. How can I reset data on start of adding new post?

If I've understood correctly, Firebase transactions work on only one data table.

**Main question** is: how to make transactions on multiple data tables and storage in Firebase?

Comment: You can't do a real, atomic transaction on multiple locations in the database simultaneously.  You can do a multi-location update, but that won't be safe against concurrent updates from other clients.

Comment: @DougStevenson thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're looking for something like this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#update_specific_fields. It allows you to run multiple updates all at once to wherever you need. Here is a snapshot of the code:

```
var updates = {};
updates['/posts/' + newPostKey] = ...;
updates['/user-posts/' + uid + '/' + newPostKey] = ...;

return firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try to do it in the evening 2day. I will accept, if it helps. By the way, can I add something like this for storage too? Or I should make something like upload data with completion handler and then update database like in your answer?

Comment: Thanks one more time. With storage did like this: upload with completion handler -> save data to database. Works pretty good.